# Firefox extension: use promise in browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, extension-methods

I'm working on a firefox extension and using browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener.

I need to redirect or release the webRequest until I have information back from calls made within the handler.

I used to use synchronous ajax, but the page was blocked for too long when the network was poor. If the request time exceeds 5 seconds, I want to cancel the ajax request. But it seems impossible to set a timeout on a synchronous call.

These days I try to use asynchronous ajax and use the methods(return new Promise) provided in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest. I tried several days but failed.

My codes:

```
var LOOKUP_URL = "https://a.b.c.com/";
var urlLookup = new UrlLookup(LOOKUP_URL);
var blockList = [];

browser.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(redirectAsync, {urls: ['<all_urls>']},, ["blocking"]);

function redirectAsync(details) {
    var url = details.url;
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){

        var urlLookupResult = urlLookup.check(url, LookupComplete);

        if(urlLookupResult.result){
            var redirectUrl = urlLookupResult.url;
            resolve({redirectUrl})
        }
    })
}

function LookupComplete(url, data, error){
    if(data.result){
        blockList.push(url);
        localStorage.setItem("blockList",JSON.stringify(blockList));

        return {
                result: true,
                url: "https://aaa.bbb.com/alerts.php?url=" + url;
            }
    }else {
        return null
    }
}
```

codes in urlLookup.js:

```
function UrlLookup(domain) {

    function check(url, callback) {
        var data;
        var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var timeId = window.setTimeout(function(){
            http_request.abort();
        },5000)
        http_request.open("GET", domain + 'url='+url);
        try {
            http_request.send();
            http_request.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(http_request.readyState == 4 && http_request.status == 200){
                    window.clearTimeout(timeId);
                    data = JSON.parse(http_request.response);
                    return callback(url, data);
                }
            }
        } catch (e){
            return callback(url, null, "Error");
        }
    };

    return {
        check: check
    };
}
```

How should I modify it?